# How to get all duplicates row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a tables `companies` and `addresses` and need to get all duplicated rows

Checking columns is `companies`.`phone_number` and `addresses`.`columns`

Table `companies`

| uuid | name | phone_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5esd | A INC. | 667-784-343 |
| 6dcv | B INC. | 866-653-343 |
| 56js | C INC. | 111-222-333 |
| tug8 | D INC. | 111-222-333 |
| jkj9 | E INC. | 777-666-443 |

Table `Addresses`

| id | parent_uuid | a1 | a2 | postal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5esd | st2 | st3 | 444 |
| 2 | 6dcv | st2 | st3 | 444 |
| 3 | 56js | st55 | st56 | 545 |
| 4 | tug8 | st77 | st78 | 675 |

I need four rows:

| uuid | name | phone_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5esd | A INC. | 667-784-343 |
| 6dcv | B INC. | 866-653-343 |
| 56js | C INC. | 111-222-333 |
| tug8 | D INC. | 111-222-333 |

Because two first records has same `addresses` and two last records has same `phone numbers`

Comment: yes I know that its like last question but different

but as from last question's answer I have to put MILLION if condition to get result

Comment: @ErgestBasha by the way tried this https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/d7e026e4993a17e94e30d2d7fc9c9405/

Comment: From above it looks like the needed result is the same as the companies table. Correct?

Comment: no, I need duplicated rows as I describe on question

Comment: But "I need all rows" looks exactly the same as "Table companies"...

Comment: @jarlh Because two first records has same addresses and two last records has same phone numbers

Comment: Looks like you need better sample data, something that shows the actual problem.

Comment: @jarlh yes maybe you right

Comment: It looks like you are wanting two separate queries, one for your addresses table and one for your companies table. On the addresses table, you want to return rows which have matching a1, a2, and postal columns, and on your companies table, you want to return rows with matching phone_number columns. Is this correct?

Comment: @SimonGoater correct, duplicated rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
select c.*
from companies c
where uuid in ( select parent_uuid 
                from (  select parent_uuid,
                               count(*) over(partition by a1,a2,postal) as cnt
                        from Addresses 
                       union all 
                         select uuid,
                                count(*) over(partition by phone_number) as cnt2 
                         from companies 
                      ) as tbl
                where cnt >1
              ) ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/EqGajA1t

With union all we find duplicates of each table getting the uuid and parent_uuid with duplicates and using the in operator containing the duplicated uuid and parent_uuid;

Answer (score 0):

**Something like this will give the desired output :**

```
SELECT uuid,name,phone_number
  FROM companies
  INNER JOIN Addresses
  ON companies.uuid = Addresses.parent_uuid;
```

Comment: come on! I said need to duplicated rows, not just join

Comment: you just getting all rows without where condition

Comment: Give more clearer sample data and clearer question. And what you have tried so far.

Comment: pls look to updates, thanks